# running a virtualenv python under Xcode

Tags: python, xcode, virtualenv

So far I've been able to work with Python 3 and Xcode 5.1.1 by editing the scheme, pointing the Run executable to python3 and then adding some arguments as in the following picture:

[image]

But now I would like to work with isolated Python environments through `virtualenv`. I can do this through the terminal, as I just have to type `workon pydev` where `pydev` is my Python environment. But I have no idea of how to modify my Xcode configuration so that I can run within a Python environment. Is there an environmental variable or something I can set to make this happen?

**UPDATE**

So I have a partial answer but I still can't make it work on Xcode. I created a simple bash script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

source ~/.bash_profile
workon pydev
python3 src/__main__.py
```

The source is needed because otherwise the `workon` command doesn't work (another file provided by the `virtualenv` package is sourced inside `.bash_profile`. I can run the script in the Terminal, but the problem now is that Xcode doesn't like it:

> Xcode cannot run using the selected destination.
>   Choose a destination with a supported architecture in order to run on this system.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it, so you have to add the following pre-action to Xcode.

[image]

The source is needed because otherwise the workon command doesn't work (another file provided by the virtualenv package is sourced inside .bash_profile.

Comment: In addition to your updated answer @aaragon, I had to modify the scheme's executable path to the "virtualenv" path to point to the version of python being used in that project... which is generally: /path/to/your/virtualenv/project/bin/python That's the only way Running anything in Xcode found the virtualenv relative lib path to my project.